# Is it possible to use django-celery-beat with django-tenant?

Tags: python, django, multi-tenant, django-celery, django-celery-beat

I am using celery for scheduling tasks. So far everything was fine, including hosted on AWS. However, I decided to transform my single application to multi tenant, using django-tenant. That way, I can create the subdomains perfectly.

```sh
./manage.py create_tenant
```

However, when running the command `celery -A myproject worker -B`, despite not showing me any error, It seems to me that he cannot run for the created schema (test with only one created).

I tried to specify the schema, using `python manage.py tenant_command celery worker -B --loglevel = info --schema = myschema`
but I received the following error:

```py
raise CommandError ("Unknown command:% r"% argv [2])
django.core.management.base.CommandError: Unknown command: 'celery'
```

If anyone can help me, I really appreciate It!
If It is possible to run the command for a specific schema, is It also possible to run globally for all schemas created? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should extend celery Task implementation and inject the db_schema and use it instead

But it would be also OK not to reinvent the wheel and use 
https://github.com/maciej-gol/tenant-schemas-celery

Comment: Hi @iklinac, I took a look and I understood what I have to do. Thank you very much! Tomorrow I will try and, If everything okay, I come back here and check as correct in your answer